# Using BillingDataSource.java of Android example

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am trying to use

```
BillingDataSource.java
Security.java
```

from
[TrivialDriveSample](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples)
I managed to get the purchase for a Premium SKU (one time purchase)
but where can I check if this product is bought when my App start in order to unlock features each time the App starts
I need to call from my MainActivity a method to see if it is ok

if I ask

```
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            LiveData<Boolean> IsPremiumPurchased = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).billingDataSource.isPurchased(SKU_PREMIUM);
            mIsPremium = IsPremiumPurchased.getValue();
            Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateUi();
        }
```

I got
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.MainActivity$MainFragment.onResume(MainActivity.java:1302)

because IsPremiumPurchased  is not valid

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your problem but in a few days/ a week, I'll release a new android library for `in-app purchases` that is very easy to use, so you'll not have to bother with this anymore. I'll come up with an update after release.

Comment: Update: https://github.com/moisoni97/google-inapp-billing

Comment: @MoisoniIoan Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As I see a sample use](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/6a02a11cdbdd52200ac2f64f025d3a4537ed8306/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/res/layout/inventory_item.xml) live-data and data-binding.

From your code:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).billingDataSource.isPurchased(SKU_PREMIUM)
```

You get live-data object `IsPremiumPurchased` but live-data provides observe pattern to receive new values. It's means that usually you can't get value sync by calling `IsPremiumPurchased.getValue()` because operation of getting value by key `SKU_PREMIUM` is async and will be written to `IsPremiumPurchased` after some time. That's why call to `IsPremiumPurchased.getValue()` returns `null` in your snippet([As you can see it valid behaviour](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/f9ae2d55c3699474e26ca0185a5ff38afb9df153/TrivialDriveJava/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/trivialdrivesample/ui/MakePurchaseFragment.java#L127)). Right way to use `IsPremiumPurchased` - is subscribe to updates of `IsPremiumPurchased` like in [this sample](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects).
For example you can put code like this to `onCreate` method:

```
        final Observer<Boolean> premiumPurchasedObserver = new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final Boolean isPurchased) {
                mIsPremium = isPurchased;
               ((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateUi();
            }
        };

        IsPremiumPurchased.observe(this, premiumPurchasedObserver);
        mIsPremium = IsPremiumPurchased.getValue();
        if(mIsPremium == null) {
            mIsPremium = false
        } 
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).updateUi();
```

I Add check for current value after `IsPremiumPurchased.observe` call to get consistent ui if `premiumPurchasedObserver.onChanged` will be called with long delay.

Comment: Thank you but your code doesn't even compile. What is IsPremiumPurchased ? is it premiumPurchasedObserver  ?

Comment: @Lotfi Please try to explore sample (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) from my answer. And do similar with your lifedata

Answer (score 0):

After trying, right answer is

````
billingDataSource = new BillingDataSource( this.getApplication(),
                INAPP_SKUS, SUBSCRIPTION_SKUS, AUTO_CONSUME_SKUS);
LiveData<Boolean> IsPremiumPurchased = billingDataSource.isPurchased(SKU_PREMIUM);
final Observer<Boolean> premiumPurchasedObserver = new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final Boolean isPurchased) {
                mIsPremium = isPurchased;
                updateUi();
                Log.d(TAG, "premiumPurchasedObserver changed");
            }
  };
IsPremiumPurchased.observe(this, premiumPurchasedObserver);```
````